# TFlearn - how to not send data to tensorboard each step

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tflearn

right now is TFlearn sends data to tensorboar each step and it is inefficient. It takes too much space and I don't need it. It would be much better, if it would be at the end of an epoch. Or 10 epochs.

Is it possible to set this somewhere?

Comment: Please be more clear about the context of your question and identify that you are referring to TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Otherwise your readers may be confused about the context.  You should also specify the target platform.

Comment: Well, yes and no. TFLearn is a framework build on TensorFlow. When I used pure TensorFlow, I had to send results to TensorBoard manually. Therefore I had full control.
But TFLearn sends data to TensorBoard by it self and I don't have to care about it. But unfortunately, I couldn't find a way, how to adjust frequency.

And what do you mean by target platform?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No. Tflearn evaluates the summary operations in the same line as the training operations are run, see [code](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py#L816-L817)

```
_, train_summ_str = self.session.run([self.train, self.summ_op],feed_batch)
```

This means that summary is logged for the training set at each step. That said, you can specify the `snapshot_step` and `snapshot_epoch` options in the `fit` method of `tflearn.DNN` model, such that the summary operations from the validation set is only evaluated every 10 epoch.

As @Keeehi mentions, if you really want to do this, you could implement it in pure Tensorflow, where you have much more control over what is done in each step.